# Creating Drools with member object's field in when clause

Tags: java, drools

I am new to drools, so please bear with me.
I have the following rule:

```
rule "01: Car can not be black"
  when 
    Car(color == "black")
  then 
    System.out.println("Car can not be black");
end
```

Would it work doing this (where Door is an object member having color as a member variable):

```
rule "02: Car's door can not be black"
  when 
    Car(door.color == "black")
  then 
    System.out.println("Car's door can not be black");
end
```

If not possible, what template to use to match the solution?

Comment: Yes, both the rule above is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these rules are valid, as long as your class has the appropriately named getters.

The first rule will work for a class `Car` which either has a public `color` property or it has a public `getColor` method:

```
public class Car {
  public String color;
}
// or:
public class Car {
  private String color;
  public String getColor() {
    return this.color;
  }
}
```

Similarly, the second rule will work if your `Car` class has a public `Door` property or a public `getDoor` method, and the Door has, similarly, either public `Color` or `getColor()`.

Another way to write the second rule that checks that the door is not black would be like this:

```
rule "03: Another way to make sure the car's door cannot be black"
when
  Car( $door: door != null ) // gets the Door from the car
  Door( color == "black" ) from $door // checks if the Door is black
then
  System.out.println("Car's door cannot be black");
end
```

This way is useful if you need to check other properties of the same door. For example, let's say that your car has multiple doors, and the Car model has a method like `List<Door> getDoors();`. To check if there is any black and round door, you could do:

```
rule "04: A car cannot have any black and round doors"
when
  Car( $doors: doors != null ) // get all of the Doors for the car

  // finds that any one door is both black and round:
  exists(Door( color == "black",
               shape == "round" ) from $doors) 
then
  //...
end
```

Here I used `exists` because I don't actually need to do anything with the door that is black and round, I just want to make sure it exists.

Comment: Can we put "and" and "or" in the when clause?

Comment: when Car(door.color == "black") and Car(door.shape== "round") then

Comment: In your example, if you want to check that a car door is black and a car door is round (not necessarily the _same_ door) you could do `Car( door.color =="black", door.shape == "round" )`.

Comment: If you want to check that the _same_ door is black _and_ round then you'd do like the third rule example that I posted, and check `Door(color == "black", shape == "round") from $door`. The comma in the when clause indicates "and" -- that is all of the criteria must match.

Comment: Alternatively you can `&&` and `||` criteria instead. I would recommend not using the `and` and `or` keywords because they don't always behave as you might expect.

Comment: Can I do: when 
    Car(door.color == "black") && Airplane(seat.color == "black")
  then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208729/discussion-between-roddy-of-the-frozen-peas-and-gingerhead).

Comment: Thanks so much Frozen Roddy with Peas!